# android custom regex with InputFilter

Tags: java, android, regex, android-edittext

I would to check like this Regex in my edittext. After five symbol text must append dot and after dot two symbols should input, for example XXXXX.XX (max amount 99999.99) 
I wrote custom InputFilter and It's does not working correctly .Here is a code

```
class DecimalDigitsInputFilter implements InputFilter {

    Pattern mPattern;

    public DecimalDigitsInputFilter(int digitsBeforeZero,int digitsAfterZero) {
        mPattern=Pattern.compile("[0-9]*" + (digitsBeforeZero-1) + "}+((\\.[0-9]{0," + (digitsAfterZero-1) + "})?)||(\\.)?");
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {

        Matcher matcher=mPattern.matcher(dest);
        if(!matcher.matches())
            return "";
        return null;
    }

}
```

I use this class like this

amountValue.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new DecimalDigitsInputFilter(5,2)});

Can anyone tell me what's a wrong in my code or what's a best way to create like this regex.
thanks

Comment: You have a malformed limiting quantifier and some redundant patterns. Try `Pattern.compile("[0-9]{0," + (digitsBeforeZero-1) + "}(?:\\.[0-9]{0," + (digitsAfterZero-1) + "})?")`

Comment: I think it's incorrect @Wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: You think or you tested? See [my test](https://regex101.com/r/vX4cBO/1). It works. Are you sure you need to decrement `digitsAfterZero` and `digitsBeforeZero`? Try removing `-1`: `Pattern.compile("[0-9]{0," + digitsBeforeZero + "}(?:\\.[0-9]{0," + digitsAfterZero + "})?")`

Comment: I tested it it like this  private boolean isValid(CharSequence s) {
        return mPattern.matcher(s).matches();
    }

Comment: So, what is the issue? Any error? Input is prevented? *It's does not working correctly* is not a helpful issue description. I assumed you were using the regex for live validation, hence my suggestion. For final validation, you need to remove all `0,`s